# Image is not showing while copying from one folder to another

Tags: php

I am trying to copy an image from one folder to another using PHP.
Image is moving fine, but when I am opening the image, the image is not showing.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Below is my code.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'image_copy') {
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    //name of file to be copied
    $img = $image;
    //read the file
    $fp = fopen('files/post/' . $img, 'r') or die("Could not contact $img3");
    $page_contents = "";
    $new_text = fread($fp, 100);
    $page_contents = $new_text;
    //This moves you from the current directory user to the images directory in the new user's directory
    chdir("files/profile");
    //name of your new file
    $newfile = $image;
    //create new file and write what you read from old file into it
    $fd = fopen($newfile, 'w');
    fwrite($fd, $page_contents);
    //close the file
    fclose($fd);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: could you perhaps show the `<img>` html code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have made it some other way using file get content and put content .

```html
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $dir_to_save = "files/profile/";
    if (!is_dir($dir_to_save)) {
        mkdir($dir_to_save);
    }
    file_put_contents($dir_to_save . $image, file_get_contents('files/post/' . $image));
```

But i am unable to do in move method of php.

Comment: Do u mind deleting this answer and edit your update your question with this?